# Why does a MySQL MEMORY-backed table take so much more space than on disk?

Tags: mysql, memory

I have a single InnoDB table on disk, with ~1,107,423 rows and taking up 45.6 MiB disk space.  The structure is:

```
messageid int(11)
signature varchar(255)
```

When I create a MEMORY-backed version of this table, it takes up 803.5 MiB of memory!

It seems reasonable there'd be some expansion: a lot of extra pointers from the B-tree index or something, but increasing by a factor of 16 seems awfully excessive!  What's the reason behind this?

Comment: cache alignment, possibly. you might have only a 16bit int to store, but to prevent crossing certain memory boundaries, mysql might be taking 8 bytes to store it in.

Comment: Please post SHOW CREATE TABLE of the table

Answer (score 4):

VARCHARs are stored with a fixed length in memory, so your max length of 255 will be using a lot of space.  Your InnoDB disk table will be storing the rows with a dynamic length.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html says...

> - MEMORY tables use a fixed-length row-storage format. Variable-length
>     types such as VARCHAR are stored using a fixed length.